# Where does Magento order/sort collection in category page

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I pass in a query string with parameters `order=price&dir=desc` to order by price from big to small. In the `list.phtml` template file 
`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection`
has orders property of an empty array, so the page refreshes but returns with the same default collection.

I tried to run `mysqladmin -u -p -i 1 processlist` 
to view the queries to the db , but no query to the products has been passed (cache is off).

I tried to debug but apparently it works by events and its very hard for me to find in what classes:

1.The acctual query to the DB happens

2.The sorting takes place

Perhaps someone has some experience why it does not sort. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

//First below class used for sorting category.

```
File Path : Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php
```

//Following function used for sorting collection.

```
public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $this->_collection = $collection;

        $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

        // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
        $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
        if ($limit) {
            $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
        }
                if($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'review'){
            $this->_collection->sortByReview($this->getCurrentDirection());
        }
        else if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
        }
        return $this;
    }
```